# Why does this action parameter not get picked up?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, routes

I am trying to map /my/route/id to an action but the parameter id keeps coming in as null. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Controller mapping code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/alias")
public class AliasesController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody SampleAliasMaskModel index(Integer id) {
```

Code issuing the request

```
$('select[name=aliasMask]', ctx).change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (val === -1)
        return maskSelected(null);
    if (!_.isNaN(val))
        $.getJSON('alias/'+val, {}, function(mask){
            maskSelected(mask);
        });
})
```

The request itself:
[image: chrome request that fails]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If spring isn't compiled with debug information you have to specify the name of the Pathvariable as annotation parameter.

Like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/alias")
public class AliasesController {

@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody SampleAliasMaskModel index(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
```

Maybe that's the reason.